# RewriteRule in .htaccess not redirecting properly on WAMP Server for login form

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

I have WAMP Server installed on my Windows computer. I have a system that uses the PHP Slim framework. In my .htaccess file, I have the following redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(contact|login|unsubscribe|activation|activation-again|forgot-pass|banned|manage-profile|manage-acount|profile-settings|terms|privacy|faq|blog|clubs|browse|basic_search|online|timeline|permission-requests|my-validations|my-fans|my-gifts|my-invitations|gift_wheel|gift_select|my-visitors|my-reviews|my-blocklist|my_pictures|my_videos|my_xcoins|xcoin_acount|what_is_matcmeter|what_is_trust_score|medical_reports|picture|video|webcam_verification|quick_settings|my_messages|my_messagesV2|my_orders|site-maps|logout|welcome|signup|data/xcoin_islem_list)$ /$1.php?lang=en [L]

RewriteRule /faq/detail/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)?$    /faq_detail.php?t_tbl=faq_contents&t_cat_id=$1&t_cat_name=$2&t_id=$3&t_title=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule /faq/categories/(.*?)/(.*?)?$    /faq_categories.php?t_tbl=faq_categories&t_cat_id=$1&t_cat_name=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule /blog/detail/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)?$    /blog_detail.php?t_tbl=blog_contents&t_cat_id=$1&t_cat_name=$2&t_id=$3&t_title=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule /blog/categories/(.*?)/(.*?)?$    /blog_categories.php?t_tbl=blog_categories&t_cat_id=$1&t_cat_name=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule /profile/(.*?)?$    /member_profile.php?t_tbl=members&name=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule /create-events/(.*?)?$    /create-events.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule /show-feedback/(.*?)/(.*?)?$    /show-feedback.php?id=$1&name=$2 [QSA,NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /api/index.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

/login.php

```
<div class="sign-user_card rounded pl-2 pr-2 pt-3 pb-3 shadow">
    <div class="sign-in-page-data">
        <div class="sign-in-from w-100 m-auto">
                                            
            <form class="mt-4" method="post" action="/login/do">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>E-mail address</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" class="form-control kar_tem_func" name="f_user" id="f_user">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" value="" class="form-control kar_tem_func" name="f_pass" id="f_pass">
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center links">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log in</input>
    </div>
        
</div>
```

Slim framework - Routes.php

```
$app->post('/login/do', function (Request $request, Response $response) {

    /*      The login operations take place here.    */

      $alert_text= 'OK!';

      return $response
      ->withStatus(200)
      ->withHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json')
      ->withJson(array([
          "id" => 1,
          "alert_text" => $alert_text
      ]));

    exit();
});
```

The issue I'm facing is as follows:

I have a login form on the `http://localhost/login` address. When I fill out the form and click the submit button, it should send the entered values to the `http://localhost/login/do` address. However, instead of doing that, it redirects to the `http://localhost/login` address. The same code works perfectly on a Linux server. It seems that the `RewriteRule` in the `.htaccess` file redirects to the "login" without considering the rest of the URL.

Changing the form's post URL to `http://localhost/DoLogin` resolves the issue. Is there a way to fix this problem without changing the post URL?

Comment: What other directives do you have in the `.htaccess` file? How is the URL `http://localhost/login/do` meant to be processed? The rule you've posted should not apply here. "it redirects to the `http://localhost/login` address" - You actually see an external redirect - the URL in the address bar changes (or remains at) to `/login`?

Comment: Since it works on Linux, it is probably not a configuration error.  Turn on full trace mode (LogLevel trace8) in your configuration to see exactly what the rewrite engine is doing.  Note we do not see the rest of the configuration, is everything else exactly the same?  Ex. is you WAMP configured with mod_rewrite loaded?  Did you `RewriteEngine On`?